# Browser Same Origin Policy - why is RSS data considered dangerous?

Tags: javascript, cors, rss, fetch-api, same-origin-policy

Modern browsers prevent scripts fetching [RSS feeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) from sites out of the domain of the running script.
The RSS feed gets transmitted but the browser's [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) won't let you access it.
Only feeds from servers that specify the [CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin) header can be read.

Why?

We are not talking about malicious scripts - just XML data.
What is the thinking behind considering an RSS feed as a potential danger?
How could it be exploited?

Comment: It's more about reading data that shouldn't be accessed than running malicious scripts.

Comment: @konrad-linkowski - but would be just poor access control.  The RSS can still be downloaded using a download manager or even `wget`.  That does not make any sense.

Comment: But your wget doesn't carry an auth cookie which can be used to access your personal data on the site that also uses rss.

Comment: @konrad-linkowski But most news feeds don't authenticate by cookies or by logins.

Comment: But the domain that sends a newsfeed can also host a service that can be logged into. It's about possibilities not things that are usually done

Comment: @konrad-linkowski  so all major web-browsers implement a blanket block just so that insecure servers don't leak otherwise publicly available feeds?  Still does not make much sense to me.

Comment: That mechanism was added when websites existed, but ajax did not yet. To make ajax possible and not make all existing servers set additional headers, by default requests like that were blocked.

Comment: @konrad-linkowski - not really:  ajax preceded CORS by several years.  Ajax W3C Standard 2006; CORS W3C Standard 2014.  I know I was programming way back then!

Comment: So what prevented accessing other domains with cookies back then?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Before the advent of CORS, AJAX did not allow you to issue cross-origin requests, only same-origin ones.

Comment: "But most news feeds don't authenticate by cookies or by logins" — The browser can't tell if it only has access to an RSS feed because it has a cookie, some other login, IP address validation, or it is on a LAN accessing a corporate intranet feed. Cross origin access for the last 20 years or so has been designed on a secure-by-default principle.

Comment: @Quentin how is it secure-by-default to permit images and scripts to receive cross origin access but disallow data feeds — such as RSS?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff — "Cross origin access **for the last 20 years or so** has been designed on a secure-by-default principle." Images and scripts predate that window. (There's also less of a problem with a browser displaying an image or executing a script cross origin then there is giving the data to a script written by a third party that could forward the data to their own server).

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff A page can embed a cross-origin image or load an external script, but a client (i.e. some JS code running in the context of that page) cannot read the response to requesting that image or script, thanks to the SOP. At most, in the case of an embedded image, the client can access the dimensions of the image. This difference matters.

Comment: @Quentin "less of a problem with a browser displaying an image or executing a script cross origin then there is giving the data to a script written by a third party that could forward the data to their own server" - but why shouldn't a third party forward data to their own server?  Is it a question of ownership or of protecting the browser?

Comment: @jub0bs data cannot manipulate things like a script can - so why  is it treated as if it could?

Comment: Alice works for Major Bank. Alice visits Mallory's evil website. Mallory's JavaScript runs in Alice's browser. Mallory's JS makes an HTTP request from Alice's browser to Major Bank's internal corporate Intranet. It downloads the bank's internal financial report before it has been even released to shareholders. It sends that report to Mallory. Mallory now has insider information to manipulate the stock exchange with. How would this **not** be a problem?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff Again (read my answer below), the point is not to protect the client from the requested resource; it's the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

> Only feeds from servers that specify the CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header can be read.

> so all major web-browsers implement a blanket block just so that insecure servers don't leak otherwise publicly available feeds? Still does not make much sense to me.

By default, the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) won't let a client read the response to a cross-origin request, regardless of whether the requested resource is publicly accessible. CORS is a protocol for the server to instruct a browser to selectively relax some of the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions (both in terms of reading and sending) on network access to a resource from some requesting client.

There's nothing special about an RSS feed. In the case you describe, it's just one cross-origin resource among others. Carving out an exception for RSS feeds in the SOP would have needlessly complicated it.

> The RSS can still be downloaded using a download manager or even wget. That does not make any sense.

True, but the SOP was never meant as a substitute for server-side access control; for one thing, it's only enforced in browsers, not in other user agents like curl or Postman. Rather, the SOP is meant to protect [Web origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) from one another.

> why is RSS data considered dangerous?

> We are not talking about malicious scripts - just XML data. What is the thinking behind considering an RSS feed as a potential danger? How could it be exploited?

You've got it backwards. The SOP's restrictions on network access are not meant to defend the client against a malicious resource. Instead, they're meant to defend the resource against a malicious cross-origin client, which might for example attempt to exfiltrate data from the resource.

If you control the resource in question, you can override the default behaviour of browsers and configure CORS to allow clients from any Web origin to read the response from the requested resource.

> ajax preceded CORS by several years. Ajax W3C Standard 2006; CORS W3C Standard 2014. I know I was programming way back then!

Support for cross-origin requests with AJAX only came later than 2006, prompting the need to devise the CORS protocol. See [XMLHttpRequest Level 2, W3C Working Draft 25 February 2008](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20080225/):

> XMLHttpRequest Level 2 enhances XMLHttpRequest with new features, such as **cross-site requests** [...]

(my emphasis)

Note that "cross-site" should be understood as "cross-origin", here. The difference matters now that "site" has a [more technical meaning](https://web.dev/same-site-same-origin/).

Besides, CORS support was added to major browsers in the later 2000s. It didn't wait until the 2014 W3C standard.

Comment: This still doesn't explain why browsers don't even allow a script to make a fully anonymous request that doesn't send any credentials and therefore wouldn't cause a security issue for the resource.

Comment: @Jez Incorrect. Browsers _do_ in fact allow clients to send so-called simple and anonymous requests. For instance, open your browser's Console tab on this page and run `fetch('//example.com')`. Your browser will happily send an anonymous `GET` request to `https://example.com`. In accordance with the SOP, your browser will prevent `https://stackoverflow.com` from reading the response, but it _will_ send the request.

Comment: @Jez Besides, in some situations, a request doesn't need to be authenticated to cause damage. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks/254684#254684

Comment: Yeah well obviously I meant a request where the script can see the response.  As for the examples in the link, well I guess it's a trade-off.  IMHO those risks are extremely minor compared to the huge loss of functionality of not being able to get anonymous resources (without CORS headers, which are frequently not set).

Comment: @Jez I wouldn't call the possibility of a malicious public Web page exfiltrating stuff from someone's corporate intranet as "minor". But if you're feeling so strongly about the Same-Origin Policy, I urge you to take your complaint to the WHATWG `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: If the internet were properly implemented with a login mechanism (I can't see an argument for not doing so), it wouldn't an issue.

Answer (score -1):

First a big thanks to all the commenters and to @jub0bs for his considered and detailed answer.  You all gave me a lot of food for thought.

However it has since dawned on me that XML data such as RSS can embed text that contains `<script>` tags and those tags, once fetched, might be inadvertently inserted verbatim (using innerHTML or similar DOM methods) - and this would be equivalent to any other Cross-site script (XSS) exploit.
So RSS should be considered dangerous.

The remedy according [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) is **not** to use innerHTML when incorporating fetched data.